# How would I create a button that would remove a selected object from my jlist

Tags: java, swing, defaultlistmodel

This is my current attempt

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Remove Selected Shape");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel<Node> model = (DefaultListModel<Node>)itemList.getModel();
            Node selectedShape = itemList.getSelectedValue();
            model.removeElement(selectedShape);
            updateList();
        }
    });
```

I think I had a better approach before, but can not remember.

This is how my list is displayed

```
JList<Node> itemList = new JList<Node>(model);
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(itemList);
```

I have these initialized in my class

```
private JFrame frame;
private NodePlot plot;
JList<Node> itemList;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
private DefaultListModel<Node> model = new DefaultListModel<Node>();
```

Comment: What is the problem? Looks fine to me. All you need to do is remove the selected item from the ListModel. The JList will repaint itself automatically. You don't need the updateList() method. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` is a complete working example.

Comment: @camickr thank you for your feedback I removed the updateList() method and it is now functional.